# Validation: Explaining Reasons

Tags: html, validation

Could someone explain to me what I am getting the validation errors that I am for my website:

```
 Line 33, Column 216: Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.
…ilto:?subject=E-mail%20from%20.co.nz">e-mail</a>.<p/>

Line 43, Column 72: Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
…www.twitter.com/" title="Follow me on Twitter"><li class="twitter"></li></a>
```

**Code:**

```
<p>Text<a href="mailto:"">e-mail</a>.</p>

            <div id="socialMedia">
                <ul>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"title="Follow me on Twitter"><li class="twitter"></li></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" title="Like me on Facebook"><li class="facebook"></li></a>
```

The `li` class is linked to an image that displays and can be clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch your `<a>` tags and `<li>` tags; the `<li>` should be on the outside, and is the only allowed element directly inside the `<ul>`.

```
<div id="socialMedia">
                <ul>
                    <li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/" title="Follow me on Twitter"></a></li>
                    <li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/" title="Like me on Facebook"></a></li>
```

Without seeing what's on line 33 of your site- or maybe the few previous lines before it- it's hard to tell what the self-closing-tag error is; it looks like you're using /> on an `a` tag directly instead of a seperate closing `</a>`.